# C/C++ streams and files

Tags: c, stream, fopen, freopen

I have the following code:

```
int checkCorrectness(int i,char *iStr)
{
   if(atoi(iStr) == i)
     return 1;
   return 0;
}
void foo(int i)
{
    printf("inside foo %d\n",i);
}
void print()
{
    char mystring[100];
    freopen("myfile.txt","w+",stdout);
    for(int i =0;i < 100;++i)
    {
      foo(i);
      FILE *f = fopen("myfile.txt","r");
      if (f == NULL) perror ("Error opening file");
      else {
         while ( fgets (mystring , 100 , f) != NULL );
         if(!checkCorrectness(i,mystring);
            break;
         fclose (f);

      }
     }
    fclose(stdout);
}
```

Is this code save?I mean is it OK to call fopen after freopen was called and its stream was not closed?                              Thank you

Comment: why are you using C file functions in C++....
also you should really be using string objects, not directly acting on memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks safe. You are allowed to open the same file more than once in a process. The file descriptors will not interract.

I'd steer away from reopening stdout like you do. You could do this entire program with a single fopen and avoid the mess you're creating: look up fprintf!

Comment: I know but I have to use printf only!The question was also if opening and closing myfile.txt will allow printf to continue to write to the myfile and will not generate mess in streams

Comment: The way you've done it is nasty. Why are you allowed to use prinf only? Homework question? And, "f" is completely independent of "stdout" so yes, you can do that. You _shouldn't_ do that, but you can.